# How to set up MYSQL Tables for fast SELECT

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

The question is about *.FIT files ([link to definition](https://developer.garmin.com/fit/protocol/)) (1 to extremely many and constantly more), from Sports watches, speedometers,
in which there is always a timestamp (1 to n seconds), as well as 1 to n further parameters (which also have either a timestamp or a counter from 1 to x).

To perform data analysis, I need the data in the database to calculate e.g. the heart rates in relation to the altitude over several FIT files / training units / time periods.

Because of the changing number of parameters in a FIT file (depending on the connected devices, the device that created the file, etc.) and the possibility to integrate more/new parameters in the future, my idea was to have a separate table for each parameter instead of writing everything in one big table (which would then have extremely many "empty" cells whenever a parameter is not present in a FIT file).

Basic tables:

**1 x tbl_file**

| id | filename | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz.fit | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | vwx.fit | 2022-01-02 |
| .. | .. | .. |

**n x tbl_parameter_xy / tbl_ parameter_yz / ....**

| id | timestamp/counter | file_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | value |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | value |
| 3 | 0 | 2 | value |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

And these parameter tables would then be linked to each other via the *file_id* as well as to the FIT File.

I then used a test server, set up a MYSQL-DB to test this and was shocked:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_parameter_xy as x
LEFT JOIN tbl_parameter_yz as y
ON x.file_id = y.file_id
WHERE x.file_id = 999
```

Took almost **30 seconds** to give me the results.

In my parameter tables there are **209918** rows.
file_id 999 consists of **1964** rows.
But my SELECT with JOIN returns **3857269** rows, so there must be an/the error and that's the reason why it takes 30sec.

In comparison, fetching from a "large complete" table was done in **0.5 seconds**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_all_parameters 
WHERE file_id = 999
```

After some research, I came across INDEX and thought I had the solution.
I created an index (file_id) for each of the parameter tables, but the result was even slower/same.

Right now I´m thinking about building that big "one in all" table, which makes it easier to handle **and** faster to select from, but I would have to update it frequently to insert new cols for new parameters. And I´m afraid it will grow so big it kills itself

I have 2 questions:

- *Which table setup is recommended, primary with focus on SELECT speed, secondary with size of DB.*
- *Do I have a basic bug in my SELECT that makes it so slow?*

[EXPLAIN SELECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFaxj.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. (Click on 'Edit'.) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] PS Please ask 1 question. [ask] [Help] PS You need to define "best" & then say how you are stuck deciding on it. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Please avoid social & meta content.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have any `INDEXes`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for a few of the tables.  Please provide realistic names, no "xy"; that will help me think through the schema.

Comment: Yes I had too little indexes and even worse the "combinatorial explosion" O. Jones pointed out. With his Input I´m good atm, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a combinatorial explosion in your JOIN. Your result set contains one output row for every pair of input rows in your two parameter tables.

If you say

```
  SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b
```

with no ON condition at all you get COUNT(a) * COUNT(b) rows in your result set. And you said this

```
  SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b WHERE a.file_id = b.file_id
```

which gives you a similarly bloated result set.

You need another ON condition... possibly try this.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_parameter_xy as x
  LEFT JOIN tbl_parameter_yz as y
         ON x.file_id = y.file_id
        AND x.timestamp = y.timestamp
```

if the timestamps in the two tables are somehow in sync.

But, with respect, I don't think you have a very good database design yet.
This is a tricky kind of data for which to create an optimal database layout, because it's extensible.

If you find yourself with a design where you routinely create new tables in production (for example, when adding a new device type) you almost certainly have misdesigned you database.

An approach you might take is creating an attribute / value table.  It will have a lot of rows in it, but they'll be short and easy to index.

Your observations will go into a table like this.

```
file_id       part of your primary key 
parameter_id  part of your primary key
timestamp     part of your primary key
value
```

Then, when you need to, say, retrieve parameters 2 and 3 from a particular file, you would do

```
    SELECT timestamp, parameter_id, value
      FROM observation_table
     WHERE file_id = xxxx
       AND parameter_id IN (2,3)
     ORDER BY timestamp, parameter_id
```

The multicolumn primary key I suggested will optimize this particular query.

Once you have this working, read about denormalization.

Comment: Thnx a lot, with second ON condition I´m at correct 1964 rows in 2sec :)
Thing is, timestamp is not reliable, as sometimes it´s a real timestamp, sometimes just a number counting upwards (although I could fix that in INSERT).
But you are right, the design is flawed if I have to add tables now and then, so right now I´m trying to build the observation table, which sounds like a very good idea. I would need one "observation table" and one table for description, right? (where I link parameter_id to e.g. parameter_name, parameter_unit, etc..) 
I will report tomorrow how it worked out, thnx!

Comment: If this were my project I'd write some code to regularize your data when you load it into the database -- put a timestamp on every row, even if it must be inferred somehow. If you will analyze data from different parameters together, you will have to do this somewhere in your app. Best to do it when loading (when you have access to the raw data files and streams).